# colorAccent cannot be overridden by child theme

Tags: android, android-styles

I have a base style for the whole application, and a child style for a text view. But in the child style, the "accentColor" item is not taking effective. The text view still uses the accentColor from the parent style.

Here is my style.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#00ff00</item> <!-- Green color -->
</style>

<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">#ff0000</item> <!-- Red color -->
</style>

</resources>
```

Here is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="io.github.seemuch.highlightexperiment.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:textColorHighlight=""
    style="@style/TextViewTheme"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the screenshot of the app:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JKNa.png)

As you can see, the highlight color of the text view is green, which is AppTheme's accentColor, not the TextViewTheme's.

I just want to change the color of the text highlight. I know that the highlight part itself can be changed by adding a "textColorHighlight" attribute to the text view, but that does not change the color of the "anchor". The only way that I found was to change the accent color, but I also do not want to change the accent color of the whole app.

Anybody knows how to make the accentColor in the child style work? Or is there a better way to change the anchors' color?

Comment: you can add a theme to a specific activity in the `manifest.xml` inside the `<activity>` tag  which will override the the `AppTheme`

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't have "android:style" instead of just "style"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`colorAccent` is a theme attribute, not a style attribute as per the [Themes and Styles I/O 2016 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TIHXGwRTMWI).

Therefore you need to apply it with `android:theme`, not with `style`:

```
<TextView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Hello World!"
  android:textIsSelectable="true"
  android:textColorHighlight=""
  android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme"/>
```

And your `MyCustomTheme` should generally have a parent of `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat` as it overlays the default theme (changing only the things it defines) rather than resetting everything from the parent theme.

Comment: Are you sure this will work? The way I understand, Themes can only be applies to Applications, Activities, and ContextWrappers.

Comment: That's not been the case since Lollipop and AppCompat v21.

Comment: @lionscribe - yep, watch the talk I linked and don't read the docs if you want to know how it works now.